# get percentage from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

im kinda try to create a voting system, i had 2 option, when i just choose one of them for the first time, the percentage is not showing the percentage result. here's the code

html

```
voting yok<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="choose" value="cat">cat<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="choose" value="dog">dog<br>
<button id="vote">vote!</button>
<p id="hasil"></p>
```

JS

```
   let btnvote = document.getElementById('vote');
  let cat = 0
  let catp = 0
  let dog = 0
  let dogp = 0
  btnvote.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let hasil = document.getElementById('hasil')
    let pilihan = $("input[class=choose]:checked").val()
    $(".choose").prop("checked", false);
    switch (pilihan) {
      case 'cat':
        cat += 1
        break;
      case 'dog':
        dog += 1
    }
    setInterval(() => {
      catp = cat / (dog + cat) * 100
      dogp = dog / (cat + dog) * 100
    }, 1000);
    hasil.innerText = `cat : ${cat}/${catp.toFixed(1)}%, dog : ${dog}/${dogp.toFixed(1)}%`
  })
```

or you can check it on https://jsfiddle.net/p1w60dab/2/
thanks for any help/suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have the percentage calculations wrapped in a setInterval. I'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve there.

If you remove the setInterval everything should work as expected.

```
 let btnvote = document.getElementById('vote')

  let cat = 0
  let catp = 0
  let dog = 0
  let dogp = 0
  btnvote.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let hasil = document.getElementById('hasil')
    let pilihan = $("input[class=choose]:checked").val()
    $(".choose").prop("checked", false);
    switch (pilihan) {
      case 'cat':
        cat += 1
        break;
      case 'dog':
        dog += 1
    }
  
     catp = cat / (dog + cat) * 100
     dogp = dog / (cat + dog) * 100
  
    hasil.innerText = `cat : ${cat}/${catp.toFixed(0)}%, dog : ${dog}/${dogp.toFixed(0)}%`
  })
```

Comment: i wrap them in setInterval because i think, that way it could updated the value every 1 second. but its not really effective i think. but thanks anyway!

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as correct! Thanks!